# C++ : Math library that solve system of equations using back substitution algorithm

Tags: c++, math, matrix

If I have this:

```
A * f = g;
A: upper triangular matrix (n x n)
f: (n x 1)
g: (n x 1)
```

Need to solve for `f` using back substitution algorithm. I would say that it not really that hard to write one myself, but oh well, if there is a library out there, then why not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost [uBlas](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) should work. At least if I understand your question correctly, you probably want to start by looking at `lu_substitute()` and `inplace_solve()`.

Comment: thank you very much, the library seems very robust, however it is a bit more than what I needed so I ended up write my own. However I would definitely recommend ppl to look at this library. `:M1& tsm(  M1 & m1, const T & t, const M2 & m2, C )`

Answer (score 3):

Use the [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/index.html).  It's already installed on many systems, and there are many implementations available for systems that don't have it.

Specifically, the routine you want is `dtrtrs` or `strtrs`, depending on whether your data is in double- or single-precision.

Comment: From a quick glance at their site: "LAPACK is written in Fortran90..." Not that you can't get C++ to call Fortran, but it can be somewhat inconvenient.

Comment: The language that a library is written in doesn't matter; there's a standardized C interface, and the library is available on most every platform so you don't generally need to build it yourself.  If you do need to build it for some reason, there's a C version of the library (CLAPACK) as well.  It's the industry standard, and the most portable solution by far.

Answer (score 0):

Is it one of these? I haven't heard of solving systems of linear equations with "back substitution" before. Why does it have to be back substitution?

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialAdvancedLinearAlgebra.html

Comment: Triangular matrices are special in that no factorization is necessary to solve the system, and the standard method (which is also the grade-school algebra method) of solving them is called "back substitution" if the matrix is upper triangular, because you first solve for x[n], then x[n-1], then x[n-2], etc...

Comment: Oh. I haven't heard of it being called that before.
Did a quick check  with eigen. It has it...but it's not "official yet" whatever that means.
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a89efaba57cb2952b65868b4d679ce954

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity & lack of dependencies, I'd go for [JAMA+TNT](http://math.nist.gov/tnt/download.html) and use the [`LU` class](http://math.nist.gov/tnt/jama_doxygen/class_JAMA__LU.html) for factorization and its `solve()` method. There doesn't appear to be a way you can initialize LU with a pre-existing upper triangular matrix (LU's constructor makes no assumptions and just starts factoring) but I would think you could either use it as is, and live with the performance hit of the redundant factoring, or just take solve method and adapt it to your needs.